# Verbe dans « Qu'est-ce que la guerre civile ? »

Tags: grammaire, questions

> Qu'est-ce que la guerre civile?

Pourquoi il n'y a pas de verbe dans cette phrase?

Comment: Alors, pourquoi la phrase n'est pas construite comme ca: Qu'est-ce que la guerre civile est?

Comment: The same reason you could say 'What is civil war ?' and not 'what is civil war is ?'

Comment: Dans ce cas, je ne comprends pas le 
rôle du mot ,,que" avant la guerre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a verb in this sentence.

Its archaic form would be :

> **Qu'**est** la guerre civile ?* (Spanish *¿Qué es la guerra civil?*)

but it is never used. The issue is related to the verb *être* at the singular because at the plural it is more acceptable and with other verbs like *changer* or *devenir*, the forms are common day-to-day French :

> *Que **sont** les guerres civiles ?*
>
> *Que **change** la guerre civile ?*
>
> *Que **devient** la guerre civile ?*

A formal, literary way can be :

> *Qu'**est**-ce, la guerre civile ?*

The standard written way to ask it is the one you found :

> *Qu'**est**-ce que la guerre civile ?*

where ***qu'est-ce que*** can be considered as a single invariable<sup>1</sup> pronominal entity, probably the reason why you didn't identify the verb hidden in it.

A more informal / spoken French, is :

> *Qu'**est**-ce que c'**est** que la guerre civile ?*

where there are two verbs, often a puzzling phrasing for non native speakers.

Finally, the more common and simpler way to ask this question nowadays in spoken French is :

> *C'**est** quoi, la guerre civile ?*

<sup>1</sup><sub>We can't say :</sub>
 <sub>**Que sont-ce que les guerres civiles ?*</sub>

Comment: Merci beaucoup, mais effectivement oui, j'ai du mal à comprendre pourquoi il y a deux verbes dans une phrase.  Je suppose que je dois le tout simplement accepter.

Answer (score 3):

> Qu'**est**-ce que la guerre civile?

Le verbe être est utilisé ici à la troisième personne du singulier ***"est"***

> je suis
>   tu es
>   il est
>   nous sommes
>   vous êtes
>   ils sont
>
> *Source: [the-conjugation](https://www.the-conjugation.com/french/verb/etre.php)*

Answer (score 0):

COMPLÉMENT DE RÉPONSE

question

Alors, pourquoi la phrase n'est pas construite comme ca: Qu'est-ce que la guerre civile est?

On ne dirait pas « Qu'est-ce que la guerre civile est ? » mais « Qu'est-ce qu'est la guerre civile ? » ([ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=qu%27est-ce+qu%27est&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cqu%27est%20-%20ce%20qu%27est%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cqu'est%20-%20ce%20qu'est%3B%2Cc0) [ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=que+la+*+est+%3F&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)).

NOTE : il faut cliquer « search lots of books » to get the ngram1.

La raison est tout simplement qu'il y a le choix entre les deux formes, ou plutôt entre trois formes, comme on dit aussi « Qu'est-ce que c'est la guerre civile ? ».

Answer (score 0):

This sentence contain a verbe : 'est', it is asking the question 'what is civil war'

It is making a question by inverting verb and subject from :

```
Ce qu'est la guerre civile: ... <explication de ce qu'est la guerre civile>...

ce qu'est => Qu'est-ce que...
```